# Game login server

Tags: mysql

I have a setup like this:
A website, with a database.  This database houses accounts and all details. Password hashes/salts/join dates/etc.  What I want to do is to be able to use this same database for our game database.  The game will be on servers in the United States while the web server and web server database is in the Netherlands.  I know there is a big problem with using remote SQL and we really don't want to do that as operation of the website is just as vital as operation of the game server.

We had one solution that involved sending account details to another database hosted on the same server that the gameserver is hosted on, but that was incredibly unreliable because if the website was down, no new people could register to play the game.

The solution that we want is to have a log in server that is used to check credentials for everything.  Is this possible/viable and could anyone point in the right direction?

So, in summation:

2 game servers
1 web servers
1 central database used for authorization.  The game accounts and website accounts need to be one in the same.

Answer (score 2):

> but that was incredibly unreliable because if the website was down, no new people could register to play the game

Use mysql dual master asynchronous replication. Both ends can update. Both ends replicate.

Answer (score 0):

Does the game server need to write to the database or only perform `SELECT` queries for user authentication? If it only needs read access, then I'd just do what you were doing before - replicate all or a subset of your website database to the game server. Having a separate authentication database wouldn't protect you from the failure scenario you outlined - either way, if the webserver is down, no one is going to be able to register whether its user database is local or in some central location.

Comment: The accounts are the same for the game and the website.  The game will have another database for character information that won't need to be accessed from the web server.

Answer (score 0):

What about creating a [slave replica database](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replication-howto.html) on the US game server with the auth details from the NL website database?